# What is this creature on the back of Harry Potter 2 Illustrated Edition?

Tags: harry-potter

I was just looking at this dust cover of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* (Illustrated Edition) and noticed this creature. My first guess as to what it was was a Bowtruckle but Bowtruckles aren't that big.

> Maximum of eight inches in height, made of bark and twigs with two small
>
> [*Bowtruckles-Pottermore*](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/bowtruckles)

So if anyone could help me out that would be great!

[image: Image of the dust cover showing the creature circled]

Comment: For context, the [full cover](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CtREC4_WIAAF8JP.jpg) shows that this is the Weasleys' yard.

Comment: That's definitely a Groot..

Comment: Maybe Treebeard?

Comment: You-know-who, but not who you know.

Comment: Because [every image on a Harry Potter cover](https://goo.gl/images/gCt9W7) draws from the book its covering.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## It is a reference to *A Monster Calls*, which Jim Kay also worked on and illustrated. It is apparently "a sort of Green Man".

In short it is a Green Man which was a reference to Jim Kay's work on *A Monster Calls*. See the bottom half of my answer for an email I received from him that this is the case.

The creature on the front cover of *A Monster Calls* does also look a lot similar to the one on the dust cover.

[image: A Monster Calls front cover]

I haven’t actually read or seen this either but Jim Kay also worked on the film and again the creature in the film is very similar.

[image: A Monster Calls film still showing a similar creature]

---

I emailed Jim Kay from his contact form on [Creepy Scrawlers Ltd](https://creepyscrawlers.com/contact/) and this is the response I got.

> Hello,
>
> I've just noticed this creature on the Dust Cover of Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (Illustrated Edition).
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/44eE6.jpg
>
> I've also seen that apparently it was revealed at some point what it was (potentially in The Prisoner of Azkaban illustrated edition but I can't see if it is).
>
> Have you revealed what it is and if so what is it?

> **It's a sort of Green Man, I illustrated A Monster Calls**, which kind of changed my life really. Wouldn't be illustrating today if it wasn't for that book by Patrick Ness.  I worked on the film too. **It was just a little nod to that really.**
>
> There are other things people haven't noticed yet. On the Chocolate bar wrapper in the chapter opener inside Prisoner of Azkaban, there is a black dog hidden among the hares.  Best Wishes
>
> J

[image: Screenshot of the quoted email above]

Answer (score 8):

I hate making this an answer rather than a comment, but I can't post the image in a comment. I reached out to artist Jim Kay and asked him directly - he responded that the answer is revealed in the third book. Anyone w/ that book feel free to answer and I'll toast this post

> [image: Screenshot of conversation]
>
> [...] creature hidden in the trees behind the Weasley's Quidditch pitch is meant to be. It appears to be a humanoid of some sort, like an Ent or something and was just curious. Thank you!
>
> Neat time i revealed.
>
> Ah interesting! Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in the book that resembles this image aside from 'Dumbledore with a phoenix on his head'; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw6l3jW99z0

Comment: @NKCampbell I reached out to him and apparently it is just a reference to _A Monster Calls_. See [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/205572/58193).

Answer (score 3):

## It resembles the Bloomsbury logo

This may be an ["Easter egg"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) regarding the publisher of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* (Illustrated Edition).

The Bloomsbury Publishing logo — seen in the bottom right corner of the cover — features a humanoid archer with antlers:

[image: Bloomsbury logo]

*— [Image source](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d7/92/f6/d792f6a5c4e1ea07a11fd8a033e78d38.jpg)*

On the cover, the figure among the trees is similarly depicted as a silhouette, apparently with antlers.

[Jim Kay](http://www.jimkay.co.uk/), the book's artist, included a number of [hidden details in his illustrations for the previous novel](http://www.mugglenet.com/2016/01/easter-eggs-in-jim-kays-illustrations-for-harry-potter-and-the-sorcerers-stone/).  While many of these details come from *Harry Potter* canon, the appearance in Diagon Alley of Kay's dog Leroy is whimsical, just as a hidden publisher's logo might be.